# constexpr position in variable declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Usually I like to put "const" behind the type, as

```
int const foo1 = 123;
```

Now, if i want to declare a second variable (which should even be constexpr) I would like to use the same style:

```
int constexpr foo2 = 123;
```

However, this led to a warning upon running a code analysis tool (however, all compilers I tried accept it).
Does the C++ standard mandate that constexpr can only be used before the actual type?

Comment: note that 'const int' is a different type than 'int'. however constexpr does not modify the type, but rather the linkage, like for example static or inline

Comment: Please include the warning you mentioned

Comment: @eike It is an inhouse company style checker so I'd like not to include it here. My question is just about whether its valid c++ code to put the constexpr after the type.

Comment: An inhouse style checker... oh dear. It is uncommon to see it written like that (it is allowed), so maybe its better to update the style checker

Comment: @PepijnKramer but on the other hand it's a STYLE checker and, as you said, it's quite uncommon to see it written like that, so a warning from the style checker might be exactly what the company wants there.

Comment: Relatively short video on the topic: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6s6bacI424>

Comment: @StefanRiedel Fair enough. I understood that the style checker just doesn't know what to do with constexpr. The o dear is kind of twofold, maintaining your own companies style check guidelines is tedious (been there, roi is low, time is better spent on static code analysis etc..) and style guidelines usually ends in endless opinion based discussion (also kind of waste of effort). So that's why :)

Comment: What is the difference between `const int` and `int const`?

Comment: @CaglayanDOKME there is no difference at all

Comment: @CaglayanDOKME They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr` is a *decl-specifier*, as are `int` and `const`.

Other *decl-specifiers* are for example `thread_local`, `mutable`, `extern`, `virtual`, `extern`, `friend`, `typedef`, `consteval`, `constinit` and `inline`, as well as other *type-specifiers* such as `volatile`, `long`, `double`, `auto`, `signed`, `decltype(...)`, names of types, types introduced by `class`, `enum`, `union`, `struct`, etc.

A sequence of *decl-specifiers* makes up the *decl-specifier-seq* of a declaration. Following the *decl-specifier-seq* is typically a list of declarators, separated by commas, which declare the entities with the given decl-specifiers. (But for example the `*` in `int* s;` is part of the declarator, not the specifier sequence.)

I don't think there is any instance in the standard where the order of the *decl-specifier-seq* has any relevance. For example the following compiles without issue and should have the same meaning as in the conventional order of specifiers:

```
struct { double volatile mutable long x = 1; } typedef const S;
inline S thread_local constexpr *s = {};
```

See the post-C++20 draft of the C++ standard, section [[dcl.spec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec). It specifies the grammar of the decl-specifier-seq and the individual specifiers. In the rest of the section certain combinations of specifiers are forbidden, but their order is not mentioned.

---

So

```
int constexpr x;
```

and

```
constexpr int x;
```

are equivalent.

But what is not possible is e.g.

```
int* constexpr x;
```

The `constexpr` would here be part of the declarator. It could be written as

```
int constexpr* x;
```

though.

I suppose that makes putting `constexpr` as a rule after the type specifier confusing. It is the same rule as for `const`, but `constexpr` should only ever apply to the whole declaration, not to the type or a subtype.

---

I think it is likely that the code analysis tool is simply complaining about the style rather than the functionality of the syntax. It is unusual to place `constexpr` behind the type specifiers, as it is unusual to put e.g. `const` between the two `long` in `long long`, and if the specifiers are in uncommon order it may become hard to read the code.

Comment: Just to help readers. Also see this: [East const but constexpr West - Dan Saks](https://youtu.be/z6s6bacI424)